# AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention for TableColumnAttribute

Tags: azure-mobile-services

in the xxxContext.OnModelCreating generated for .NET backend is a statement: 
    `modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(
    new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<TableColumnAttribute, string>(
    "ServiceTableColumn", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnType.ToString()));`

Why is this wiring for the ServiceTableColumns in the App Code? Is this a possible hook?

Kind regards,

Markus